# How to prevent Chart1.DataSource=null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Chartid.DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceID"
If I again give 
Chartid.DataSourceID=datatable reference from a business logic

If throws an error saying can't use both datasources...,remove one.

On removing datasource, while calling chartid.databind();
on hitting the breakpoint,  I realized my datasource=null occurs after post back condition.

Please guide me in eliminating this error.

here is design:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ImageLocation="~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"> <Series> 
<asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Pie" ChartArea="ChartArea1" XValueMember="Target_Category" YValueMembers="Orders" Color="Green" XValueType="String" YValueType="Double" >
</asp:Series> 
</Series> 
<ChartAreas> 
<asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" > 
<Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" Rotation="90" Inclination="0"/> </asp:ChartArea> </ChartAreas> 
</asp:Chart>
```

here is code:

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Target_Category"; 
Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Orders"; 
Chart1.Series["Series1"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "outside"; 
Chart1.Series["Series1"]["PointWidth"] = "0.1"; 
int User_Id = User_ID; 
SessionParameter spuid = new SessionParameter();
spuid.Name = "User_Id"; 
spuid.Type = TypeCode.Int32; 
spuid.SessionField =Convert.ToInt32( Session["User_Id"]).ToString(); 
Chart1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1"; 
Chart1.DataBind() ; Chart1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: post you code please thanks

Comment: Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Target_Category";
Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Orders";
Chart1.Series["Series1"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "outside";
Chart1.Series["Series1"]["PointWidth"] = "0.1";
int User_Id = User_ID;
SessionParameter spuid = new SessionParameter();
spuid.Name = "User_Id";
spuid.Type = TypeCode.Int32;
spuid.SessionField =Convert.ToInt32( Session["User_Id"]).ToString();
Chart1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";  Chart1.DataBind() ;
Chart1.Visible = true;

Comment: <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
 ImageLocation="~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" 
ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation">
<Series>
<asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Pie" ChartArea="ChartArea1" 
 XValueMember="Target_Category" YValueMembers="Orders" Color="Green" 
XValueType="String"  YValueType="Double"
 ></asp:Series>
</Series>
<ChartAreas>
<asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" >
<Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" Rotation="90" Inclination="0"/>
</asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>

Comment: please post it in the question it is unreadable

Comment: I'm unable to post in the question..